# layout weight doesn't work when set the height to 0dp

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a relativelayout contain inside of it:
1)linearlayout with viewflipper inside it
2)recycleview

I'm trying to make the linear layout with the flipper take 30% height of screen
and the recycleview take the rest of size screen

so I used framelayout between these two just to divide the screen but it's not good solution so I delete the framelayout and used the weightlayout with linearlayout and recycleview but when I set the height of linearlayout to 0dp the images of viewflipper just disappear

this is the code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="giga.net.world.gn.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/content_frame">
        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/slider"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/world" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/tv" />
        </ViewFlipper>
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/content_frame"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

what should I do to make the flipper take 30% of screen height and make the recycleview take the rest 70% of screen height
and the framelayout is not important I can delete it if it require that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are diving wrong . you have to set weight for child views and it will divide views as per orientation . See layout below :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10">

<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/slider"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/world" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/tv" />
</ViewFlipper>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_weight="7"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/content_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/slider"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/pic" />
        </ViewFlipper>

    <!--<FrameLayout-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/content_frame"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="0dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="0dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"-->
        <!--android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>-->

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use LinearLayout as the root element and set the `android:weightSum` to value "10"
and `android:orientation`to "vertical"
Then you have to set height of ViewFlipper and RecyclerView to 0 dp and add them the attribute `android:layout_weight` to "3" and "7". It means that ViewFlipper will take 3/10 heights and RecyclerView will take 7/10.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/content_navigation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
              android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">

        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/slider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                 />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                />
        </ViewFlipper>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```